# Autoscale to fit images between paragraphs

Tags: spacing, graphics, minipage, fit

Does anyone know to to place an image to fill up a space between paragraphs?

My situation is that I have two `minipages` that must fall on the same page, but they dont take up all the space. Right now I have them separated by using `vfill` like so.

```
\clearpage

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    about 3 inches worth of text
\end{minipage}

\vfill

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    about 3 inches worth of text
\end{minipage}

\clearpage
```

I have the following code snippet that I use to fill horizontal lines with dots, I tried modifying it to work vertically but to no end.

```
\def\mydots{\leavevmode\xleaders\hbox to 0.25em{\hfil.\hfil}\hfill\kern0pt}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: So, instead of `\vfill` you want to insert something like a `\vfilldots`?

Comment: Maybe? Essentially I want to auto scale the image to fit the space that the `vfill` takes up. So while I dont want dots, maybe the method is similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the positions of the top/bottom of the `\vfill` using [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module, and then stretch an image to fill this space:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-savepos,graphicx}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \strut\lipsum[1]\strut
\end{minipage}

\zsavepos{top}% Save top of \vfill

\vfill

\noindent\zsavepos{bottom}%
\raisebox{.5\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]
  {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\dimexpr\zposy{top}sp-\zposy{bottom}sp+.5\baselineskip]{example-image}}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \strut\lipsum[2]\strut
\end{minipage}

\clearpage

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Since this seemed like a one-time use event, the code is contained as-is in the document. However, if you wish to do this more frequently, one could wrap the content in a (say) `\vfillimage[..]{...}` macro.

The above technique uses LaTeX's `\label`-`\ref` system in order to track the position on the page. As such, any change in layout will require an additional compilation to settle any references. The same goes for the first processing (which will require at least two compilations).

---

Here is the above technique wrapped into a macro `\vfillgraphic*[<opts>]{<image>}`. The optional `*` inserts a `\noindent` before placing the graphic `<image>` with options `<opts>`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-savepos,graphicx}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example

\usepackage{xparse}
\newcounter{vfgcntr}
\NewDocumentCommand{\vfillgraphic}{s O{} m}{%
  \stepcounter{vfgcntr}% Make unique labels
  \zsavepos{vfg-top-\thevfgcntr}% Save top of \vfill

  \vfill

  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\noindent}% \vfillgraphic*
  \zsavepos{vfg-bottom-\thevfgcntr}% Save bottom of \vfill
  \raisebox{-.5\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]
    {\includegraphics[height=\dimexpr\zposy{vfg-top-\thevfgcntr}sp-\zposy{vfg-bottom-\thevfgcntr}sp+.5\baselineskip,#2]{#3}}
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \strut\lipsum[1]\strut
\end{minipage}

\vfillgraphic*[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \strut\lipsum[2]\strut
\end{minipage}

\clearpage

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

For multiple uses of `\vfillgraphic`, you need to avoid multiply-defined `\label`s. As such, a unique counter `vfgcntr` is added to every label.

Comment: Hey thank you very much. Im going to try to figure out how to make a macro around this.

Comment: Here was the solution I came up with, I added a `\centerline` and tweaked the hight a little bit to add more room underneath the top paragraph.

`    \newcommand{\vfillimage}[1] {
        \zsavepos{top}% Save top of \vfill

        \vfill

        \noindent\zsavepos{bottom}%
        \raisebox{.5\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]
          {\centerline{\includegraphics[height=\dimexpr\zposy{top}sp-\zposy{bottom}sp+0.3\baselineskip]{#1}}}
        }`