# How to autoscale Figure Environment to fit page with text

Tags: graphics, scale

I'm trying to complete a scientific report and am  struggling to scale a figure (and its caption) onto a page that is partially filled with text, so that it occupies the remaining space space.

**This is my current page(s)**
[image]
**This is what I want to create instead**- where the figure auto-scales to fill the remaining space on the page, even if I add/remove some content.
[image]

Here is the code for the Current page, with many of the unneeded packages/preamble removed

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Surface Processes}
    \subsection{Atmosphere}
    \subsection{Temperature}
        Since 2009, the Diviner Lunar Radiometer Experiment on-board the Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter (LRO) has been acquiring thermal emission measurements of the lunar surface to map the daytime, nighttime and Polar surface thermal environments. The LRE's primary goal is to provide detailed thermal maps of PSRs and adjacent areas to place first-order constraints on viable cold-traps for water ice. Of the nine channels, four are dedicated to measuring the surface thermal emissions including 13–23 $\mu$m ($>$178 K), 25–41 $\mu$m (69 - 178 K), 50–100 $\mu$m (43 - 69 K) and 100–400$\mu$m ($<$43K). The bolometric brightness temperature, ($T_bol$) is a measure of the spectrally integrated flux of infrared radiation emerging from the surface, and is the most fundamental and interpretable measurably quantity for the purposes of quantifying the overall heat balance of the surface and comparing with available models \citep{Paige2010}. \cite{Williams2017} determine the $T_{bol}$,  from the combined brightness temperatures of the individual Diviner spectral channels, providing a diurnal temperature curve of the lunar surface at different latitudes (Figure \ref{fig:Williams2017 Bolometric Surface Temp}).
        \newline

            \begin{figure} [h]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/Williams 2017 bolometric surface temperature.jpg}
                \caption{(a) Zonal mean bolometric temperatures and (b) standard deviation versus local time for latitude bands 0°, 30°, 45° 60°, 70°, 80°, and 85° \citep{Williams2017}}
                \label{fig:Williams2017 Bolometric Surface Temp}
            \end{figure}
        
        \clearpage
```

I've tried the [zref-sapos solution here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227722/autoscale-to-fit-images-between-paragraphs), but it didn't allow me to include a caption. I also tried the [Tiks solution here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562538/autoscale-tikzpicture-to-maximum-size-possible-on-a-page), but it didn't work for me, as I'm not familiar with how to alter it as my figure is not using Tiks. Also, when I use the simple approach [suggested by David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132781/vertically-fit-a-figure-with-caption-to-page), no matter what pt value I put in as **"\textheight-22.2pt"** nothing changes with the figure.

I'm still new to overleaf, so am unsure how to approach the issue, any solution that I can simply include in a \begin{figure} environment would be awesome.

Cheers

Comment: Code I used following David Carlisle approach, (Overfull \hbox (22.13637pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 29--30)

           `\begin{figure} [h]`
            `\centering`
            `\includegraphics[height=\dimexpr\textheight-22.14pt\relax]{Images/Williams 2017 bolometric surface temperature.jpg}`
            `\caption{(a) Zonal mean bolometric temperatures and (b) standard deviation versus local time for latitude bands 0°, 30°, 45° 60°, 70°, 80°, and 85° \citep{Williams2017}}`
            `\label{fig:Williams2017 Bolometric Temp}`
        `\end{figure}`

Comment: just replace `width=\textwidth` by `height=6cm` and adjust as needed, there is no point in doing complicated calculations this is a pne-off adjustment for final publication positioning.

Comment: also remove the `\newline` (you must get a warning about that) . Unrelated to anything but why are your source lines so long? As you see here it makes it hard to read, with everything scrolled off screen

Comment: for your comment that simply means your image is too wide, so make it smaller. just start with height=1cm and increase it until it looks right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This computes the remaining space and scales the image height to fit.  I had to make some additional changes to get it to run without access to your files.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\autoscale}[2]% #1 = image filename, #2 = caption
{\par\bgroup
  \dimen0=\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax
  \noindent\begin{minipage}[c][\dimen0][b]{\columnwidth}
    \def\@captype{figure}% or use \captionof{figure}
    \setbox0=\vbox{\caption{#2}}% measure caption height
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height={\dimexpr \dimen0-\intextsep-\ht0-\dp0}]{#1}\par
    \unvbox0
  \end{minipage}%
\egroup\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Surface Processes}
    \subsection{Atmosphere}
    \subsection{Temperature}
        Since 2009, the Diviner Lunar Radiometer Experiment on-board the Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter (LRO) has been acquiring thermal emission measurements of the lunar surface to map the daytime, nighttime and Polar surface thermal environments. The LRE's primary goal is to provide detailed thermal maps of PSRs and adjacent areas to place first-order constraints on viable cold-traps for water ice. Of the nine channels, four are dedicated to measuring the surface thermal emissions including 13–23 $\mu$m ($>$178 K), 25–41 $\mu$m (69 - 178 K), 50–100 $\mu$m (43 - 69 K) and 100–400$\mu$m ($<$43K). The bolometric brightness temperature, ($T_bol$) is a measure of the spectrally integrated flux of infrared radiation emerging from the surface, and is the most fundamental and interpretable measurably quantity for the purposes of quantifying the overall heat balance of the surface and comparing with available models (cite removed)determine the $T_{bol}$,  from the combined brightness temperatures of the individual Diviner spectral channels, providing a diurnal temperature curve of the lunar surface at different latitudes (Figure \ref{fig:Williams2017 Bolometric Surface Temp}).

\autoscale{example-image}{(a) Zonal mean bolometric temperatures and (b) standard deviation versus local time for latitude bands $0^\circ, 30^\circ, 45^\circ, 60^\circ, 70^\circ, 80^\circ, \textrm{and } 85^\circ $ (cite removed)\label{fig:Williams2017 Bolometric Surface Temp}}

next page starts here
\end{document}
```